# How to share Vuetify customVariables with localVue instance during jest test?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js

I am using Nuxt to set global variables in `nuxt.config.js`, via `customVariables: [...]`. It works fine.

However in Jest tests I get `SassError`, when I try to access Vuetify's custom variable:

```
SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
63 │       color: $active-color;
   │              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I tried to pass `customVariables` into Vuetify constructor during the test, but it still doesn't work, like this:

```js
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import upload from '@/pages/upload'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const localVue = createLocalVue()

describe('upload.vue', () => {
  let vuetify


  beforeEach(() => {
    vuetify = new Vuetify({
      customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
      theme: {
        options: {
          customProperties: true
        }
      }
    })
```

How to fix the error above and make `localVue` instance to use `customVariables` of Vuetify?